# 1 part steganography, 1 part riddle

Tags: riddle, steganography

There's a sound that stands out to me that's sweeter than the rest.
It sings; the melody of the vowels, the consonants, are audible glee.
I don't know if it's an imagery type of situation or what, but it's amazing.
The thing about it that's really strange is that it's nothing extraordinary.
It's just a couple of words that you have certainly heard before.
Many houses will have one, but they are more often found where it is usually cold.
Crap, I—did I just give it away?
No, I'm sure that a tiny hint won't spoil the secret of this puzzle.
Anyways, back to the phrasing at hand that's currently under steady discussion.
I'm really interested to find out if this phrase similarly affects others, too.
If you don't like this one, please tell me if anything similar pushes your button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you

> count the letters in each line and convert to ASCII characters

you get

> [CELLAR DOOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellar_door).

It may or may not amuse you that

> as soon as I read the text I was 90% confident that that would turn out to be the answer :-).

Comment: Color me amused!